# Parsing XML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am querying the Microsoft Office SharePoint Server Search Service to write some results into a web part. I have the query working correctly but am having some trouble parsing the xml response via JQuery.

Below is the XML response

```
<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
  <Response domain="QDomain">
  <Range>
  <StartAt>1</StartAt> 
  <Count>1</Count> 
  <TotalAvailable>1</TotalAvailable> 
  <Results>
  <Document xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">
  <Action>
  <LinkUrl fileExt="aspx">https://mysite.domain.inc:443/Person.aspx?guid=4A4F27E2 9C99 4866 BB08 DE494475A4E7</LinkUrl> 
  </Action>
  <Properties xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document">
  <Property>
  <Name>TITLE</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>Smith, Joseph</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>RANK</Name> 
  <Type>Int64</Type> 
  <Value>873</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>SIZE</Name> 
  <Type>Int64</Type> 
  <Value>0</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>DESCRIPTION</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>Hi guys!</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>WRITE</Name> 
  <Type>DateTime</Type> 
  <Value>2009 07 31T03:00:24 04:00</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>PATH</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>https://mysite.domain.inc:443/Person.aspx?guid=4A4F27E2 9C99 4866 BB08 DE494475A4E7</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>JOBTITLE</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>Programmer</Value> 
  </Property>
  </Properties>
  </Document>
  </Results>
  </Range>
  <Status>SUCCESS</Status> 
  </Response>
  </ResponsePacket>
```

**I'm trying to get the TITLE i.e. Smith, Joseph and the JOBTITLE i.e Programmer using JQuery.**

I started with:

```
$(xml).find('Properties').each(function(){
  //not sure how to get the ones I want, use an indexer?
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
var title;
var jobTitle;

$('Property Name', 'Properties').each(function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() === "TITLE") {
    title = $this.nextAll("Value").text();
  }
  if ($this.text() === "JOBTITLE") {
    jobTitle = $this.nextAll("Value").text();
  }

});

return {
            "title" : title,
            "jobTitle" : jobTitle
       }
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ufiyu)** with your XML.

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments, I have made the assumption that the XML is part of the document. If the XML is not part of the document, then change the following line

```
$('Property Name', 'Properties').each(function() { ...
```

to

```
$('Property Name', xml).each(function() {
```

where `xml` is the service xml response.

Comment: You might want to add that this code assumes that the XML is part of the document. If not, you will have to do $(xml) for this code to work.

Answer (score 3):

These tutorials seem good: [jQuery and XML revisited](http://blog.reindel.com/2007/09/24/jquery-and-xml-revisited/), [Reading XML with jQuery](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/).

If you are able to get the data as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) you will have it easier as far as using/manipulating your data in JavaScript. And you might see performance-gains, depending on the amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

[Working Demo →](http://jsbin.com/ecuba)

```
  <script>

    var xml = '<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">  <Response domain="QDomain">  <Range>  <StartAt>1</StartAt>   <Count>1</Count>   <TotalAvailable>1</TotalAvailable>   <Results>  <Document xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">  <Action>  <LinkUrl fileExt="aspx">https://mysite.domain.inc:443/Person.aspx?guid=4A4F27E2 9C99 4866 BB08 DE494475A4E7</LinkUrl>   </Action>  <Properties xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document">  <Property>  <Name>TITLE</Name>   <Type>String</Type>   <Value>Smith, Joseph</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>RANK</Name>   <Type>Int64</Type>   <Value>873</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>SIZE</Name>   <Type>Int64</Type>   <Value>0</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>DESCRIPTION</Name>   <Type>String</Type>   <Value>Hi guys!</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>WRITE</Name>   <Type>DateTime</Type>   <Value>2009 07 31T03:00:24 04:00</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>PATH</Name>   <Type>String</Type>   <Value>https://mysite.domain.inc:443/Person.aspx?guid=4A4F27E2 9C99 4866 BB08 DE494475A4E7</Value>   </Property>  <Property>  <Name>JOBTITLE</Name>   <Type>String</Type>   <Value>Programmer</Value>   </Property>  </Properties>  </Document>  </Results>  </Range>  <Status>SUCCESS</Status>   </Response>  </ResponsePacket>';

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            var title, jobTitle;
            $(xml).find('Property > Name').each(
                function()
                {
                    $name = $(this);
                    if($name.text() === 'TITLE')
                        title = $name.parent().find('value').text();

                    if($name.text() === 'JOBTITLE')
                        jobTitle = $name.parent().find('value').text(); 
                }
             );

             alert(title);
             alert(jobTitle);
        }
    );

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came very close to getting it with pure selectors - `$(xml).find("Name:contains(TITLE)").nextAll("Value").text()` but because you wanted title and jobtitle it broke.

Anyway, I figure I'll throw my solution in there as it's a little different - the main idea is that there's only 1 if to get any key.

```
function getValue(children, key) {
  var ret;
  children.find("Name").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == key) {
      ret = $(this).nextAll("Value").text();
      return;
    }
  });
  return ret;
}

var children = $(xml).find("Property");
var name = getValue(children, "TITLE");
var jobTitle = getValue(children, "JOBTITLE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there an option that allows you to get the items back as `JSON` instead?

Comment: Not that I know of, these are the inbuilt search, old ASMX style Web services built into Sharepoint